# Find the middle of unknown size list

Tags: algorithm

In a recent interview I was asked:

Find the middle element of a sorted List of unknown length starting from the first position.

I responded with this:

Have 2 position counters:

counter1
counter2

Increment counter1 by 1 and counter2 by 2. When counter 2 reaches the end of the list counter 1 will be in the middle. I feel that this isn't efficient because I am revisiting nodes I have already seen. Either way, is there a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: This is `O(N)` time and `O(1)` space; seems pretty good to me.

Comment: If the length is unknown, which operations are allowed? Is it a _linked list_?

Comment: I was thinking that you could do something similar but the same counters but instead of jumping 2, jump a larger amount. Jump the distance of the counter that is jumping by 1 and then when you reach your boundary count by one. Is this better, invalid or flawed?

Comment: wat was interviewer response then?

Comment: @segFault: The type of list (or at least, allowed operations) needs to be shared to give the best answer.  Strilanc gave a great answer for a linked list (+1).  I gave what I think is an optimal answer for an array backed list (which your previous comment seems to imply).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming a linked list, you can do it while visiting arbitrarily-close-to N of the items.

To do 5/4 N:

- Iterate over the list until you hit the end, counting the items.
- Drop an anchor at every power of 2'th element. Track the last 2 anchors.
- Iterate the before-last anchor until it reaches the middle of the list.

When you hit the end of the list, the before-last anchor is before the mid-point but at least half way there already. So N for the full iteration + at most 1/4 N for the anchor = 5/4 N.

Dropping anchors more frequently, such as at every ceiling power of 1.5^th item, gets you as close to N as needed (at the cost of tracking more anchors; but for any given X as the power step, the asymptotic memory is constant).

Comment: Great answer. Not sure what the binary search is for though; if it's an array we can do much better than that from the outset.

Comment: I meant an array where you don't know the exact length, but can check if a given position exceeds the length. Maybe it's a bloom filter with no false positives and 0..N inserted. I'll remove that case since it's so odd and trivial.

Comment: @Strilanc If you figure out a way to make a bloom filter with no false positives, please let us know.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're discussing a linked-list. Indeed your solution is an excellent one. An alternative would be to simply traverse the list counting the number of elements, and then start over from the beginning, traversing half the counted amount. Both methods end up traversing `3n/2` nodes, so there isn't much difference.

It's possible there may be slight cache advantages to either method depending on the architecture; the first method might have the advantage of having cached nodes which could mean quicker retrieval if the cache is large enough before the two pointers are two far apart. Alternatively, the cache might get better blocks if we traverse the list in one go, rather than keeping two pointers alive.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you can detect that you're beyond the end of the list and seek an arbitrary position efficiently within the list, you could keep doubling the presumed length of the list (guess the length is 1, then 2, then 4, ...) until you're past the end of the list, then use a binary search between the last attempted value less than the length of the list and the first value that exceeded the end of the list to find the actual end of the list.

Then, seek the position END_OF_LIST / 2.

That way, you do not have to visit every node.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could do this in one traversal if you used O(N) memory (assuming you're using a linked list).

1. Traverse the list and convert it into an array (of pointers if this is a linked list).
2. Return arr[N/2]

Edit: I do love your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the regular in-memory linked list that allows reading the next element given the reference to the current multiple times (disclaimer, not tested, but the idea should work):

```
// assume non-empty list
slow = fast = first;
count = 0;

while (fast)
{
  fast = fast.next;

  if (!fast)
    break;

  count++;
  fast = fast.next;

  if (fast)
    count++;

  slow = slow.next;
}

if (count % 2)
  return slow.data;
else
  return (slow.data + slow.next.data)/2.0;
```

A more difficult case is when the "list" is not a linked list in memory, but rather a stream that you can read in sorted order and what to read each element only once for which I do not have a nice solution.